# How to order by name if order by a number is repeated in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I query my table to get the name and order from `temp_tbl`:

```
Select name, sequence from temp_tbl order by [order]
```

The above query return this resultset like this..

[image]

I have to apply a logic here, since I order by [order] and the in the above resultset it returns me two 3 and two 5, In such cases i need to order by name for the repeated numbers in order column

The expected result is

[image]

How can I achieve this in SQL query or stored procedure ?

Comment: Did you try anything?  Just order by `[order], [name]`.

Comment: You mean like `order by [order],name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple terms in the `ORDER BY` clause.  These terms are treated in descending order, so the first term takes precedence; then if there is ambiguity within that order, use the second term, and so on.  So:

```
select name, sequence 
from temp_tbl 
order by [order], name
```